# How to remove repeated lines from file with awk/sed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I'm postprocessing a very large file which contains many frames. Occasionally there is an empty frame. I would like to remove these. For example,

file.txt

```
TIMESTEP
101
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O 1 2 3
H 2 1 3
C 1 1 2
TIMESTEP
102
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
TIMESTEP
103
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O -1 2 3
H  1 2 3
C  0 1 1
...
```

I would like to obtain

file.txt

```
TIMESTEP
101
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O 1 2 3
H 2 1 3
C 1 1 2
TIMESTEP
103
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O -1 2 3
H  1 2 3
C  0 1 1
...
```

I've tried

```
sed '/3.*/{:a;N;N;N;N;/.*NUMBER OF ATOMS$/d;ba}' file.txt
```

but that would remove also valid frames, which is **not** what I want. Any pointers and advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/TIMESTEP/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n/&/5p' file
```

Gather up frames (records) in the hold space and only print them if they are 6 or more lines long.

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu awk` may do:

```
awk -v RS=TIMESTEP  'NF>15 {print RS$0}' file
TIMESTEP
101
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O 1 2 3
H 2 1 3
C 1 1 2

TIMESTEP
103
NUMBER OF ATOMS
3
ATOMS x y z
O -1 2 3
H  1 2 3
C  0 1 1
...
```

By setting record selector to `TIMESTEP` it works in block mode with each block start with `TIMESTEP`.  Then count number of fields (may need to adjust).  If its more than 15 (9 should be ok as a minimum), print the block

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed that would be just:

```
sed -z 's/TIMESTEP\n[0-9]*\nNUMBER OF ATOMS\n[0-9]*\nATOMS x y z\nTIMESTEP/TIMESTEP/g' file.txt
```

Without `-z` sed option, the following seems to work:

```
sed -n '
  # buffor 6 (not 5!, so one too much) lines into pattern space
    N;N;N;N;N

    : again

    # if pattern space matches empty frame
        /^TIMESTEP\n[0-9]*\nNUMBER OF ATOMS\n[0-9]*\nATOMS x y z\nTIMESTEP$/{
            # print just the next TIMESTEP
            s/.*/TIMESTEP/
            p
            # start from the top
            d
        }

        # if this is the last line
        ${
            # if last line is an empty frame
            /^[^\n]*\nTIMESTEP\n[0-9]*\nNUMBER OF ATOMS\n[0-9]*\nATOMS x y z$/{
                # print the line we have too much
                P
                # and end it
                d
            }

            # print until end of line
            p
            d
        }

    # just print and delete one line
        P
        s/^[^\n]*\n//
        # read next line
        N

    b again

'
```

Answer (score 0):

with gnu `awk`:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0}END{ for(i=0;i<NR;)if(a[i]=="TIMESTEP" && a[i+5]=="TIMESTEP") {i=i+5;} else {print a[i]; i=i+1;} }' file
```

Comment: OP request `I'm postprocessing a very large file`, and since this stores the whole file in an array, it may not have enough resources to handle this.big files.

Comment: yeah, u are right (upvote from me). 
btw, if u change ur name's first later to 'Ts' u get my name. :3